# CSS height 100% in firefox not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS that behaves totally different in Firefox and Chrome.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAa3y/9/).

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-table;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

In Chrome it displays correctly but not in Firefox.

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

By inspecting the content div in Firefox, the height is 0.

Why does it work in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox? 
I notice that removing the `display: inline-table` will work but the container div will be stacked instead of inline.

Comment: Changing display:inline-table to display:inline-block got it working in both browsers for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing `display: inline-table;` to `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/yAa3y/12/

I could only get it to work when I used

```
.content {
    display: inline-table;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**try this its working**

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 50px;
```

Comment: Why, and where? Please be specific.

Comment: This referes to the .container element, works for me.The trick here is to omit the height declaration and use top:0 and bottom:0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

The element does not display properly because FireFox is locking it to the size of the inner content, but I'm sure you already gathered that.

I noticed that the container height that holds the inner is fixed to 50.  If you have a fixed height for the outer container, you could match the height for the inner element.

I know this isn't the dynamic solution based on percent, but it's a work around.