# Twitter Bootstrap - Make row take up the remaining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Before people mark this question as duplicate, let me tell everyone I have tried all the suggestions that were given before in SO, especially `display: table`. That does not work with Bootstrap.

What I want to achieve is the following-:

```
---------------------
|      Nav Bar      |
|-------------------|
|      |Body |      |
|      |     |      |
|______|_____|______|
|      |     |      |
|      |     |      |
|______|_____|______|
```

The navbar must be on top. The remaining portion of the body must have 6 divs each div taking up 4 columns.

The body portion's height must be set to the remaining height, since the navbar will change according to resize.

**I am avoiding the flexbox solution because of browser compatibly. And would prefer an only CSS solution.**

This is the code I am using-:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .first_wrapper {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .navbar {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid first_wrapper">
        <!-- Navbar start -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Page</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Navbar end -->
    </div>
    <!-- Second Container -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
        <div class="row" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <div class="row" style="height:50%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:green;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:pink;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:50%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:green;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:blue;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anything after the comment "Second Container" needs to occupy the height dynamically.

Comment: there are js options, if you make a jsfiddle you are more likely to get help

Comment: @Dejan.S the question has already been edited to that

Comment: @ZimSystem Take the code snippet and run in it your browser. There must be no overflow of the second container. It must take up the remaining space of the viewport. No Scroll.

Comment: Ok, please add that to the question. Also, the inline styles are hard to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track looking at `display:table`. But you needed to take it a little further with adding row and cell styling too. By creating rows using `display:table-row` and adding the `container-fluid` elements as `display:table-cell` you're able to have them push the space the need without overflowing. The other trick is to handle the `display:inline-block` element immediately inside the body element, by setting the body `font-size` and `line-height` to 0 to combat the white space created by tabbed html, you then reset these values inside the inline-block element. *Please note that because you're using `col-lg-4` you will need to make the jsfiddle window wide enough for them to become columns.*

`display:inline-block` is notorious for leaving "gaps" between items. This is because of the "whitespace" between formatted code. There is a [great article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) about combatting this either with comments, skipping closing tags or font size. Personally, font size is much easier to maintain.

The reason to use `display:inline-block` for the containing element over `display:table` is mostly due to a firefox bug, where `display:table` doesnt render correctly, you can find the solution listed here: [CSS height 100% in firefox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956295/css-height-100-in-firefox-not-working)

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvdt891/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div class="display-table">
        <div class="display-table-row" id="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid first_wrapper display-table-cell">
                <!-- Navbar start -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Page</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- Navbar end -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-table-row">
            <div class="container-fluid display-table-cell">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:red;"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green;"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:pink;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-table-row">
            <div class="container-fluid display-table-cell">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green;"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:red;"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}

.first_wrapper {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0px;
}

#outerContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.42857143;
}
.display-table{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.display-table-row{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
.display-table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.display-table-cell > .row{
    height:100%;
}
.display-table-cell > .row > [class*="col-"]{
    height:100%;
}
#navigation.display-table-row{
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This causes a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @ZimSystem, on which browser/resolution are you seeing the scrollbar? there doesnt appear to be one on OSX Chrome at 1200+ wide

Comment: @haxxxton This is a great answer, but forgive me for troubling you further. Can you please include why you did a `display: inline-block` ? And also the rationalizing of `line-height: 0` and `font-size: 0;`. If you could edit your answer to explain more of this in detail that would be great.

Comment: @ng.newbie, updated my answer to include these requests :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ?

[image]

You have to call this CDN

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

tis is full script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .first_wrapper {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .navbar {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid first_wrapper">
        <!-- Navbar start -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Page</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Navbar end -->
    </div>
    <!-- Second Container -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
        <div class="row" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <div class="row" style="height:50%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:green;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:pink;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:50%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:green;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="height:100%;background-color:blue;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yousuf Could you please share your entire code snippet ?

Comment: yah I can, check out next ans.

Comment: @NiranYousuf No, this is not how answering works. If *this* answer is not complete, then **edit it**, don't post another answer that invalidates this one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS `calc` for the height of the container minus the navbar height.

```
<div class="container-fluid first_wrapper">
    <!-- Navbar start -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Page</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar end -->
</div>
<!-- Second Container -->
<div class="container-fluid full">

        <div class="row half">
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:pink;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row half">
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:green;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full {
    height: calc(100% - 52px);
}

.half {
    height: 50%;
}

.half > .col-lg-4 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/mkOL2syp5O

Comment: this relies quite heavily on knowing the size of the navbar and/or hoping it doesnt change size at different screen resolutions though, perhaps a warning in your answer?

Comment: The height of the navbar doesn't change, until the columns stack vertically so it really doesn't matter.