# Why Flex-box with heigh:100% works in all browsers except Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, height

After several attempts, is very tricky to find why Firefox has a different render with flexbox when the parent  (and also  and ) has height:100%
All browsers render the page without any problem (even IE11 and Edge), but Firefox can't fill all height of my parent div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="TEST" />

<style type="text/css" media="all">
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<app-root style="display:table; width:100%; height:100%;">
 <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height:100%;">

  <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; flex: 1 1 100%;">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 50%; background:yellow;">
    <div>DIV 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 1 50%; background:orange; ">
    <div>DIV 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; background:gray; padding:1rem;">
   <div>DIV Footer</div>
  </div>
   
 </div>
</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Expecting the same render for Firefox as all browsers does.

Comment: Because `app-root` has `display: table` … make that `block` instead, issue gone. (So not really a flexbox issue to begin with, I’d say.)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956295/css-height-100-in-firefox-not-working

Comment: @ThisisFish I tried to change the example code (at jsfiddle) with display:flex and removing the height 50px to 100%. Same problem and only having this bizarre behaviour in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the idea of `display:table` here, **but if you want to use it** , best is to do it from html in order to create a table of a single cell layed over the window:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<app-root style="display:table-cell; ">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height:100%;">

    <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; flex: 1 ;">
      <div style="flex: 1 1 50%; background:yellow;">
        <div>DIV 1</div>
      </div>

      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 1 50%; background:orange; ">
        <div>DIV 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; background:gray; padding:1rem;">
      <div>DIV Footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</app-root>
```

display:table with grid or flex do not go along too well , browsers gets mixed up in the way it should calculate size , rows, columns. the table-layout and grid or flex layout are very much different ;(

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyr for your quick answer, <app-root> has a display: table because i'm using this template in several pages with different components ( under Angular ) and cross-browser compatibility is a MUST ( also IE10 - 11 )

Comment: I confirm that the solution works without any problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

app-root `display: table` is changed to `display: flex`
app-root immediate child add `width:100%`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="TEST" />

<style type="text/css" media="all">
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<app-root style="display:flex; width:100%; height:100%;">
 <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height:100%;width:100%">

  <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; flex: 1 1 100%;">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 50%; background:yellow;">
    <div>DIV 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 1 50%; background:orange; ">
    <div>DIV 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; background:gray; padding:1rem;">
   <div>DIV Footer</div>
  </div>
   
 </div>
</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the thing is... display:table must be at <app-root> because will work for other pages without flexbox (i reuse under Angular other components and pages) and IE10 and 11 is needed.