# Flex Item in Display: Table, not taking height in Firefox, working fine on chrome as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent section with Display: Table; Property,

Please try to run this in Firefox.

Due to some reason I can not change this, in this section I have a Div with Display Flex and align items center,

On chrome its working fine but on Firefox flex div not taking its height, that's why I am not able to align items center.

```css
section {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
section  > div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Atul</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What is the use of `display: table;` for `section`?

Comment: This css is coming from a plugin, and I can not remove this, Removing display table is distorting the layout and giving error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by distorting, but after removing the `display` and `table-layout` properties, the code you have posted here seems to work in all browsers.

Comment: Not in the  given test case, in the plugin, which is FullPage JS, there is a section which plugin genrates, with class ".fp-section.fp-table" IF I am removing the display table then plugin is calculating the height properly and distorting the structure,  That is why I can not remove this display table from that section

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here, and someone publish the solution for me. Change your "section" from display:table to display:table-cell.
Also you need to add some css for your html and body tags.

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
html,
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}

section {
display: table-cell;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
section  > div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Atul</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Looks like Firefox has problems when display:table and flex or grid are mixed in the same hierarchy.

[Why Flex-box with heigh:100% works in all browsers except Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181611/why-flex-box-with-heigh100-works-in-all-browsers-except-firefox)